# Mac Mail.app search like functionality

Tags: jquery, macos, jquery-plugins

I was wondering if is there any jQuery plugin or something to create a search bar similar to Mac's Mail app, where you can search inside specific categories, very awesome

[image: Mac Mail App Search]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ will be a good choice.

Comment: I think the OP might be referring to the ability to type "text:" and then a search term to define a column to search.  ie. "category: fruit" "date: 12/12/12" and once you type the colon it would parse it and add a little rounded background to it.

I doubt anyone will make a jquery plugin for this, but if they do - it would be pretty incredible.  Maybe I'll give it a go soon...

The more I think about it, wouldn't be that hard... the jqueryui autocomplete could be the base of it though.  Each grouped term would be turned into another "param" in the ajax autocomplete call.

Comment: Also, pinterest has a similar markup structure for their topbar search.  The only thing it doesn't do is detect when you type ":" to parse the term before it and add it to the <span></span>'s